# How do I tap a tab in tvOS simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, tvos, apple-tv

I created a sample tvOS app in Xcode and selected "tabbed application".

Now I have a `First`, `Second` buttons at the top that looks like the equivilant of a tab bar. The simulator remote says "Press Option to touch". Pressing Option and clicking on the remote does nothing.

How do I change tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides using Apple TV Remote, you can also use keyboard `→` and `←` to select different tabs.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to interact with the tvOS Simulator.

First is the via the simulator's Apple TV Remote. This can be enabled via the simulator's menu item `Hardware->Show Apple TV Remote`:

[image: Show Apple TV Remote]

While holding the Option key on the Mac's keyboard, move the mouse cursor around the Apple TV Remote (specifically above the "Hold Option to touch" text).

[image: Option to Touch]

Another way to interact with the tvOS Simulator is via the Mac's keyboard. This can be enabled via the simulator's menu item `Hardware->Keyboard->Connect Hardware Keyboard`. Once enabled, the arrow keys are able to change focus in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you. What was confusing me is you only have to move the mouse, not click.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 12.X and beyond you should go to `Window -> Show Apple Tv Remote` or use `Shift + Command + R`.

Image

[image: 1]